# qt - how to develop application independent of screen resolution?

Tags: qt, dpi

I am beginner in qt, i am trying to develop a application which looks as image1 as shown in 1080p, but that application is to be runned on monitor with resolution 1366x768 when that application is being run on that resolution it looks like image 2.the status bar is going down and all widget pixels are expanding.
 I tried to look a solution for it and tried all possible methods such as High dpi scaling enabling and using lay outs. but in the end it did'nt solved my problem. can any one please Help me.

[image: screen shot of 1080p resolution]
[image: screen shot of 768x1366 resolution]

Comment: Since you're using Windows 10, this is controlled by the scaling option in the screen settings. Applications do not scale just because of a higher resolution. They scale because the operating system is reporting a higher DPI to the application. On Windows, the scaling slider does that.

Comment: @peterdn I have already tried that.But it dosen't work. even using layouts may be of little help but the placement of widgets is disrupted and it tooks a great pain to desgin as it is in the above shown image with the layouts.

Comment: @Nikos I am testing the application by changing the resolution in my pc. the application is getting enlarged when thier is change in resolution. I even tried changing scaling factor without changing resolution. only font is getting small or big depending on scaling. can give  a example or piece of sample code for it. I am trying this over past two weeks and seeing every attempt failing.